# VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN / Wrong URL

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have installed VisualSVN  on our server PC,and installed TortoiseSVN on 3 other(clients) PC,I'm finding it impossible to connect to the repository created on the server,Ive tried 192.168../folder/folder etc,mapping the server IP to a "name" using the hosts file. etc,any idea how to connect? Or any tutorials? I cant find anything on youtube either. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: it's not clear what URL you enter on client. "192.168../folder/folder" won't work obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check [the Getting Started guide](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/),
2. Assuming that your VisualSVN Server is accessible at https://svn.example.com and you have created a repository named MyRepo, you can use the following URL to access the MyRepo repository: `https://svn.example.com/svn/MyRepo`
3. You can start VisualSVN Server Manager, right-click repository and choose "Copy URL to Clipboard" command. Paste the URL into your client and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube's videos for development|administration tasks?! Funny...

1. Start VisialSVN Server Manager applet
2. Select root node "VisualSVN Server (Local)" on the left pane
3. On top of right pane (in section "Status"), check status of server is "running"
4. If "running", write|remeber|click on "Server URL" URL
5. Get page (root of Repository-Collection) displayed in browser
6. Select and repository from collection, copy URL and paste it into the command-line SVN-client command `svn ls` as parameter
7. Verify result of command

**READ VISUALSVN SERVER DOCS!**